# How to message user in telegram in php like telethon

Tags: php

I have a telethon python code that message telegram user by it's id or '@example' but when I run my code after a while I'm getting flood wait error

So search a lot to prevent it but nothing show

So I decided to go on php

My problem is there any code like telethon in php that can do this not creating a telegram bot but like telethon get API Id and API hash login by mobile number verify number chat telegram user and so on

Or prevent flood wait error not the try code and except code and sleep.but to prevent it and continue code

Please help me

Comment: Hi.  Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and post a [mcve].  thanks

Comment: Please help me in this